# Finite groups and noncommutative algebraic geometry

Tags: finite-groups, noncommutative-geometry

**DISCLAIMER:** My relationship with noncommutative algebraic geometry is that of a curious, ignorant bystander. I confess that I know very little about noncommutative algebraic geometry, but I am interested in finite groups and new methods/concepts/approaches in the study of finite groups.

**Question 1:**  Have there been any significant successes in applying theories of noncommutative algebraic geometry to the study of finite groups or their group algebras? Perhaps older theorems have been reformulated and proved in a more geometric fashion, or geometric methods have been applied to prove new theorems that would have been interesting to 20th-century finite group theorists?

**Question 2:** Do Sylow's theorems have a natural geometric interpretation, perhaps having something to do with localization?

I read that (at least in some flavours of noncommutative geometry) the "points" of the "space" associated with a finite group $G$ are the irreducible representations of $G$.

**Question 3:** Because of my very limited knowledge, calling the irreducible representations of $G$ a "space" looks to me like a linguistic trick that provides no new non-trivial information. **How is this idea (of irreducible representations forming a space) fruitful? What is meant by the "geometry" of this "space"?**

Comment: In characteristic zero, the representation category is too simple to apply noncommutative geometric ideas (to my knowledge), there's just no homological algebra present. In the modular case though, there are definitely parallels, though I'll let someone more qualified explain them.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that representations of finite groups show up in (commutative) algebraic geometry, particularly when studying singular surfaces. We know a great deal about surface singularities that are invariant subrings $R=S^G$, where $G$ is a finite subgroup of $GL_2(k)$ acting on $S=k[[x,y]]$ by a linear change of variable. This is because of relationships between maximal Cohen-Macaulay $R$-modules, projective indecomposable modules over the skew group ring $S\#G$, and the representation theory of $G$. https://leuschke.org/uploads/Research/CMReps-2011-12-31.pdf

Comment: I would argue that the classification of finite simple groups suggests that finite groups should be thought of as shadows of algebraic groups, which are the more fundamental objects. Even the alternating groups and others based on automorphism groups of combinatorial designs can be thought of as coming from algebraic geometry over the “field with one element”. In this sense the theory of algebraic groups, Hopf algebras, and character varieties might be a good candidate for what you’re looking for. It’s not noncommutative algebraic geometry, but at least it’s “noncocommutative”!

Comment: representations of finite groups naturally arise in invariant theory, which is one of the oldest areas of (commutative) algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 6):

For question 1, I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing you're looking for, but in work I've been doing with Radha Kessar and Markus Linckelmann, non-principal blocks of a certain family of finite groups are interpreted as (matrix rings over) quantum complete intersections. This does a lot to elucidate their modular representation theory. The quantum complete intersections in question are quotients of the quantum polynomial rings associated to quantum affine planes.

For question 2, again I don't know whether this is what you're looking for, because it's not really non-commutative, but I offer the following. If you look at cochains $C^*BG$ on the classifying space $BG$ with mod $p$ coefficients, it just "sees" $p$-local information in the following sense. It determines and is determined up to weak equivalence by the following information: the isomorphism type of a Sylow $p$-subgroup, and the fusion system and linking system on it. This is a theorem of Broto, Levi and Oliver. A much more difficult theorem of Chermak then says that the linking system is determined by the fusion system. One interpretation of this is as follows. Knowing $BG$, you can recover $G$, just as the fundamental group. But if you Bousfield-Kan complete $BG$ at a prime $p$, you can only recover the $p$-local information described above.

I have nothing to contribute to question 3.

Comment: With regards to your contribution to Question 2: does this topological perspective provide a new way to prove Sylow's (existence and uniqueness-up-to-conjugacy) theorems?

Comment: @semisimpleton I don't think so. But why would you want to use a big machine to do that?

Comment: It would be nice if there were a more conceptual/explanatory proof of Sylow's theorems.